Combine 2D and 3D lighting in Unity
I am using URP and would like to have 2D and 3D objects in the scene affected by lights.
This is not supported by Unity, however the docs said that one can use "Camera Stacking" for this exact case.

While interoperability between the respective Lights and Renderers may be developed in the future, currently a combination of 2D and 3D Lights and 2D and 3D Renderers in a single Scene can be achieved by using the camera stacking technique.

It does not work. I added two cameras first - base, second - overlay. Both with 3d renderer. Then added overlay camera to stack in base camera, then switched it's renderer to 2d renderer. Here is the message i get:
Only cameras with compatible renderer types can be stacked. The camera: Camera_1 are using the renderer Renderer2D, but the base camera: Camera are using UniversalRenderer. Will skip rendering

One option I have is to use 3D lights only.

"Does not work" is usually not enough information to troubleshoot the problem. Please edit your question to walk us through the exact steps you tried, and the specific symptoms you observe. A reader should be able to follow your instructions to go from the new project window to a demo scene that demonstrates the exact problem you're observing. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test proposed fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Use only 3d cameras and renderer.
Set the second 3d camera, used for 2d, to an orthographic projection to render the scene in 2d.
